# Is there any low level metric/logging of thread locks in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, logging, locking

Over the years, I've not really come across this if it exists, so I'm putting this out there to understand if anyone knows of any low-level .NET functionality, maybe within reflection, that can capture when a thread has become locked? Some kind of logging perhaps?

```
private object _lockObject = new object();

void MyFunc()
{
  lock(_lockObject) // <== How can I understand how many threads are waiting on this?
  {
    // Do work
  }
}
```

Is it workable to put together some kind of lock handler and pass it a predicate such as...?

```
void DoLock(object lockObject, Action predicate)
{
    push(threadid);
    lock(lockObject)
    {
      pop(threadid);
      predicate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MickyD, a semaphore just didn't seem to fit what I was trying to achieve as you typically set a single semaphore for a piece of funcationality, where as I'm looking to understand what's happening with all locks. Unless you had something else in mind and can provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can get some information via [`PerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e(v=vs.110).aspx#lockthread).

In order to do this, you will need to know the name of the process that you want to monitor.

The performance counter category name is `".NET CLR LocksAndThreads"`, and the counter names for that category are shown in the table on the page I linked above.

The monitoring is typically performed from a different process than the one being monitored, but for simplicity here is a sample console application that monitors itself:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var counter1 = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR LocksAndThreads", "Contention Rate / sec",  "ConsoleApp1");
            var counter2 = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR LocksAndThreads", "Total # of Contentions", "ConsoleApp1");

            Task.Run(() => test());
            Task.Run(() => test());
            Task.Run(() => test());
            Task.Run(() => test());

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine($"Contention: {counter1.NextValue()}/sec, Total: {counter2.NextValue()}");
            }

        }

        static object locker = new object();

        static void test()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works great for an overall picture of all locks, I suppose there's no, more granular, counters for understanding each lock, as there is no 'named' functionality to lock(). I had to replace ConsoleApp1 with `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` in order to get it to work in debug mode.

Comment: @ajb101 Sorry, but not as far as I know.